# axon framework: recreate a past situation

Tags: axon

I'm studying axon framework, I can't understand how I can recreate a past situation by limiting the events loaded by the EventStore.
I'm using this configuration:

EventSourcingRepository  repository = EventSourcingRepository.builder (ShipmentAggregate.class) .eventStore (eventStore) .build ();

how can I limit the loading of events to a given wax or to a progressive datum? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You build an Eventhandler that tracks events from the given repository source and filter the events you need using optional MetaData parameters:

```
 @EventHandler
 public void on(AnEvent evt, @Timestamp Instant eventTimestamp) {
     // if eventTimestamp < lastThursday
     // do ....
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought the framework had its own mechanism.
Thanks again.